# "bad record mac" with SSL connecting to Cloudflare on Arch Linux

Tags: https, openssl, erlang, cloudflare, archlinux

I have a simple Erlang program trying to perform an HTTPS GET. However, it fails with "bad record mac" whenever `ApiUrl` points to a domain proxied by cloudflare.

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
main([]) -> 
    inets:start(), 
    ssl:start(),
    ApiUrl = "https://remexre.xyz/",
    io:format("ApiUrl = ~p~n", [ApiUrl]),
    Request = {ApiUrl, []},
    SslOpts = [{verify, verify_none}],
    Opts = [{body_format, binary}],
    {ok, {{_, 200, _}, _, Body}} = httpc:request(get, Request, [{ssl, SslOpts}], Opts),
    io:format("~p~n", [Body]).
```

It does, however, work with non-Cloudflare HTTPS domains, including example.com and this site.

I inspected the tls stream with Wireshark, and it appears that the remote (so cloudflare) is sending the "bad record mac" to the client.

**EDIT**: This occurs on Arch Linux (multiple machines), but not on a friend's Ubuntu machine.

**EDIT 2**: [Here's the wireshark dump.](https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/0d557383947f)

**EDIT 3**: I'm on: `Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]`, which is from version `20.0.1-2` of the `erlang` package in Arch.

Comment: What Erlang/OTP version are you using? I've tried with 17.5, 18.3, 19.3 and 20.0, running the code above they all get a response successfully.

Comment: Edited to add version

Comment: I am wondering if you have resolved the problem as I also have this problem connecting a cloudflare https domain.

Comment: Nope, this is still an open bug. If you need this solved, it might make sense to contact Cloudflare support.